# How can I raise warning, using PowerShell, to limit a user to only one version of a software at a time?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have two following PowerShell commands in batch files. One is writing details of all Maya process instances to a CSV file, and other raises a warning notification.

```bash
@echo off
set "OutputFolder=Q:\.....\kartikey.s
set "ProcessName=maya"

:loop
powershell.exe -Command "Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -eq '%ProcessName%'} | Select-Object ProcessName, Id, WS, Path | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path '%OutputFolder%\ProcessData.csv'"

timeout /t 120 >nul
goto loop
```

```bash
@echo off
powershell -WindowStyle hidden -Command "[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Windows.Forms');[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Drawing');$notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon;$notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information;$notify.visible = $true;$notify.showballoontip(10,'WARNING','You're trying to open different versions of maya',[system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None)"
```

How can I merge these commands in a way that if there is a Maya instance running, and I try open another Maya of a different version, it will raise the warning notification, `You're trying to open different version of maya`.

You can get version under `Path`, from this result :

```
"ProcessName","Id","WS","Path"
"maya","8076","407134208","C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2020\bin\maya.exe"
"maya","11728","308486144","C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2020\bin\maya.exe"
"maya","22996","377659392","C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2020\bin\maya.exe"
"maya","32860","790577152","C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2023\bin\maya.exe"
```

Here it is `Maya2023`, so if I have `Maya2023` running, and if I try to open another process, (which will have some other version for example `Maya2020`), it will raise that warning.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Tip: `sort-object -unique` will remove duplicates. If you list only process paths, and there are more than one path, what does that tell you?

Comment: Why not use `Get-Process maya -FileVersionInfo` to identify the information you need.